# odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1., SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect

Tags: php, database, ms-access

I have some problem in PHP using MS Access database, when I running the query in PHP show error

> odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1., SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect

But when I'm going echo the "$query" variable and running the syntax in Microsoft Access is running well.

And this is my query:

```
<?php

// setup database for your microsoft Access
// you can setup password in you microsoft Access

// this is a variable for your connection in odbc
// "zkConnection" is your ODBC Data Source Administrator
$conn = odbc_connect("zkConnection", "", "");

// create condition for testing conecction
if ($conn) {
    // echo "<br>Connection Established</br>";
} else {
    echo "Koneksi Gagal";
}

$from_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['from_date'])) . ' 00:00:00';
$to_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['to_date'])) . ' 23:59:59';

$query = "INSERT INTO CalculateData(USERID, Name, lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, datein, timein, dateout, timeout) SELECT USERID, Name, lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, Format(CHECKTIME, \"dd/mm/yyyy\") AS datein, FORMAT(MIN(CHECKTIME), 'h:m:s') AS timein, Format(CHECKTIME, \"dd/mm/yyyy\") AS dateout, FORMAT(MAX(CHECKTIME), 'h:m:s') AS timeout
FROM TransactionLog WHERE CHECKTIME BETWEEN #$from_date# AND #$to_date#
GROUP BY USERID, Name, lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, CHECKTIME ";

if ($query) {
    //  echo $query;
}

$letsgo = odbc_exec($conn, $query);


if ($letsgo === false)
{
    die(print_r( odbc_error(), true));
}else{

}

header("location: index.php");


?>
```

And this is my table field CalculateData :
[CalculateData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WONPv.png)

And this is my table field TransactionLog :
[TransactionLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2nL7.png)

Comment: SQL Server <> MS Access - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your sql command must evaluate to something like this:

```
CHECKTIME BETWEEN #2021/09/28 00:00:00# AND #2021/09/29 23:59:59#
```

Thus, try:

```php
$from_date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_REQUEST['from_date'])) . ' 00:00:00';
$to_date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_REQUEST['to_date'])) . ' 23:59:59';

$query = "INSERT INTO CalculateData (USERID, [Name], lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, datein, timein, dateout, timeout) SELECT USERID, [Name], lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, Format(CHECKTIME, '\#yyyy/mm/dd\#') AS datein, FORMAT(MIN(CHECKTIME), '\#h:m:s\#') AS timein, Format(CHECKTIME, '\#yyyy/mm/dd\#') AS dateout, FORMAT(MAX(CHECKTIME), '\#h:m:s\#') AS timeout
FROM TransactionLog WHERE CHECKTIME BETWEEN #$from_date# AND #$to_date#
GROUP BY USERID, [Name], lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, CHECKTIME";
```

You could also try this simpler approach:

```php
SELECT USERID, [Name], lastname, CardNo, DEPTID, DEPTNAME, SUPDEPTID, DateValue(CHECKTIME) AS datein, TimeValue(MIN(CHECKTIME)) AS timein, DateValue(CHECKTIME) AS dateout, TimeValue(MAX(CHECKTIME)) AS timeout
```

Comment: when i do this, the result show this "odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Format(CHECKTIME, \#dd/mm/yyyy\#)'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in"

Comment: Yes, the format expressions are strings. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Thank You Gustav this is well and running!!!